# Lua script reports "attempt to call a nil value"

Tags: lua, roblox

I have this code:

```lua
local mob = require(script.Mob)
local map = workspace.Grassland

mob.Spawn("zombie", map)
```

that produces the following errors:

```
18:24:14.486 ServerScriptService.Main:4: attempt to call a nil value  -  Server - Main:4
18:24:14.486 Stack Begin  -  Studio
18:24:14.486 Script 'ServerScriptService.Main', Line 4  -  Studio - Main:4
18:24:14.486 Stack End  -  Studio
```

What does

```
ServerScriptService.Main:4: attempt to call a nil value
```

mean and how do I fix it?

Comment: Post the code as text on this site.

Comment: `script.mob` module returned a table without field `Spawn` defined in it.

Answer (score 0):

It means the Spawn function hasn't been defined in your module yet. please, show the `ModuleScript` so people can identify the problem. There is no problem with the Main script, there's a problem in your `ModuleScript`.